# Manual for building a virtual machine with kvm

Tags: 15.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Using this [manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/CreateGuests) I want to build a VM. However, the manual seems rather outdated: It talks about using Hardy on i386 architecture (I'm running Vivid on an x86_64). Also, `ubuntu-vm-builder` is no more than a wrapper for `python-vm-builder` these days. And all references to JeOS I can find suggest that it is no longer supported by Ubuntu. Actually Googling for `kvm` yields almost no references after circa 2013 (has it been replaced by something else?).

I would appreciate it if someone with more experience could validate the method mentioned on the referenced website. I'm a bit hesitant to do this, but can I just do `vmbuilder kvm vivid`? 
What would be some good options to start with?

I'm on `3.19.0-21-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 14 18:31:11 UTC 2015 x86_64 Linux-3.19.0-21-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-15.04-vivid`. The server has no X installed.

EDIT (14JUL2015): At this moment no answers have been given to this question and I really don't mind because I've decided to move away from `kvm` and towards `lxc/lxd`. Nevertheless, it's a pity I don't get to experience the learning curve because of the absence of a decent manual. I can't close this question with a "the problem has gone away"-reason. ;-) If an admin can, please feel free to close this question.

Comment: What do you want to use the VM for?

Comment: virtualbox has good documentation.

Comment: @muru : I want to virtualise as many of the services as possible, currently running on bare metal. DNS, DHCP, Lighttpd, etc. Each in its own VM. and more: http://www.pcworld.com/article/220644/10_Cool_Things_Virtualization_Lets_You_Do.html

Comment: You might want to checkout uvtool: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cloud-images-and-uvtool.html

Comment: Personally I suggest virt-manager it connects over ssh or a Web interface,there are several available. KVM +spice is very fast. IMO Ubuntu lags a bit with virtulization, try proxmox

Comment: I would also suggest LXD, especially if you want the VM's to run specialized to do just one thing. LXD is a little bit more lightweight but does not really have any performance penalties compared to KVM. http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/tools/lxd

Comment: @levlaz : I've heard of LXC but not of LXD. LXC being (IMHO) a glorified chroot is not exactly what I'm looking for. From your link I can't work out where to place LXD in the virtualization spectrum.

Comment: @Mausy5043 LXD is a container hypervisor :) Its a glorified chroot on crack. I think LXC is more than a chroot, I think its worth looking into especially for your use case.

Comment: @levlaz : I'm currently testing with `uvtool`. I'll give LXD/LXC a try later. Just for my understanding is LXD a kind of LXC+ or are they two different things altogether?

Comment: @Mausy5043 LXD is a Canonical Project that builds on top of LXC and make it a bit better for various use cases. Specifically when it comes to using OpenStack, security, and scalability. https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/introduction/